# Ubuntu 21.10 second monitor flickering

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hp, amd-ryzen

## Problem

The problem is that external display **HP X27i 2K resolution** are flickering hard and freezes after a few minutes of work.

On my laptop HP OMEN 16-c0024ur i have **Ubuntu 21.10** and Windows 11 dualboot.

I've tried to connect via HDMI and DP but nothing changes. On Windows the second display works well. I also tried on different distributions, like **Manjaro with 5.15 version of kernel**, but unsuccessfully.

Seems like the kernel does not support my hardware completely. There is also no driver from AMD for **RX6600m** video card .

## Specs

```
uname -r
5.13.0-35-generic
```

`CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics @ 16x 3,2GHz`

`lshw -C display`

```
*-display                 
       description: Display controller
       product: Navi 23 [Radeon RX 6600/6600 XT/6600M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: c3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:fc0-fbf iomemory:fe0-fdf irq:86 memory:fc00000000-fdffffffff memory:fe00000000-fe0fffffff memory:fc900000-fc9fffff memory:fca00000-fca1ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Cezanne
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: c5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:51 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fc800000-fc87ffff
```

#### Examples

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXmf2.jpg)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2gJw.jpg)

Comment: Hello. You mention kernel but do not say what kernel you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have resolved by installing driver from PPA third-party repository:

1. Add the repository:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
   ```
2. Upgrade the current AMD Radeon driver to the latest version:

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
   ```

[Source – Method 2](https://linuxconfig.org/amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation)